# An Example in Finite Group Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am looking for the following example.

Let $G$ be a finite group.  Let $A \leq H \leq G$ so that $A$ is self-normalizing in $H$.  Let $B \leq G$ so that $B$ acts via conjugation on $H$, and so that $B$ acts via conjugation on $A$, and so that the action of $B$ on the set of left cosets of $A$ in $H$ is "regular".  By regular, I mean that the element $eA$ in $H/A$ has orbit size one, and every other element in $H/A$ has orbit size equal to $|B|$.  Do we have an example of this happening?  If this cannot happen, does anyone have proof for why?  Thank you.

I think that the action of $B$ on $H/A$ should be well-defined, since if $xA = yA$, then $x^bA = y^bA$ for any $b \in B$.  Any thoughts?

Comment: How about $G=H=S_3$, with $A=B$ a subgroup of order $2$?

Comment: Thanks, Derek, I should’ve seen that!  Is it required that if this situation happens, then B must be a Frobenius complement and G is Frobenius?